# daily quote for each page with latex

Tags: latex

I want create calendar planner from 1/1/2019 to 31/2/2019:
In Main.tex: I use \pgfcalendar{cal}{2019-01-01}{2019-02-31} to create pdf.
One page = one day
Now i want add each different quote to each day.
How write code in quote.tex and connect in Main.tex.
Thanks

```
\pgfcalendar{cal}{2019-01-01}{2019-02-31}
{%
\LARGE\bfseries
\pgfcalendarweekdayname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday},
\pgfcalendarcurrentday{}. 
\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}
\pgfcalendarcurrentyear{}
%}
```

\pagebreak

==========

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest setting up a daily quote in Excel with all the bells and whistles of formulas to extract the [weekday](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a), [day](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DAY-function-8A7D1CBB-6C7D-4BA1-8AEA-25C134D03101), [month](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8) and [year](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-C64F017A-1354-490D-981F-578E8EC8D3B9) from a date. I pulled some [random quotes](http://veryrandomstreams.blogspot.com/2010/06/100-great-quotes-about-motivation-and.html) from the Internets to compile with each of the first 100 days...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{daily_quote.csv}
Number,Date,Day,Month,Year,DayOfWeek,Quote,Author
1,2019-01-01,1,January,2019,Tuesday,"We are what we repeatedly do. Excellence, therefore, is not an act but a habit.",Aristotle
2,2019-01-02,2,January,2019,Wednesday,The best way out is always through.,Robert Frost
3,2019-01-03,3,January,2019,Thursday,Do not wait to strike till the iron is hot; but make it hot by striking.,William B Sprague
4,2019-01-04,4,January,2019,Friday,Great spirits have always encountered violent opposition from mediocre minds.,Albert Einstein
5,2019-01-05,5,January,2019,Saturday,"Whether you think you can or think you can't, you're right.",Henry Ford
6,2019-01-06,6,January,2019,Sunday,I know for sure that what we dwell on is who we become.,Oprah Winfrey
7,2019-01-07,7,January,2019,Monday,"I've missed more than 9000 shots in my career. I've lost almost 300 games. 26 times, I've been trusted to take the game winning shot and missed. I've failed over and over and over again in my life. And that is why I succeed.",Michael Jordan
8,2019-01-08,8,January,2019,Tuesday,You must be the change you want to see in the world.,Mahatma Gandhi
9,2019-01-09,9,January,2019,Wednesday,What you get by achieving your goals is not as important as what you become by achieving your goals.,Goethe
10,2019-01-10,10,January,2019,Thursday,You can get everything in life you want if you will just help enough other people get what they want.,Zig Ziglar
11,2019-01-11,11,January,2019,Friday,"Whatever you do will be insignificant, but it is very important that you do it.",Mahatma Gandhi
12,2019-01-12,12,January,2019,Saturday,"Desire is the starting point of all achievement, not a hope, not a wish, but a keen pulsating desire which transcends everything.",Napoleon Hill
13,2019-01-13,13,January,2019,Sunday,Failure is the condiment that gives success its flavor.,Truman Capote
14,2019-01-14,14,January,2019,Monday,Vision without action is daydream. Action without vision is nightmare.,Japanese Proverb
15,2019-01-15,15,January,2019,Tuesday,"In any situation, the best thing you can do is the right thing; the next best thing you can do is the wrong thing; the worst thing you can do is nothing.",Theodore Roosevelt
16,2019-01-16,16,January,2019,Wednesday,"If you keep saying things are going to be bad, you have a chance of being a prophet.",Isaac B Singer
17,2019-01-17,17,January,2019,Thursday,Success consists of doing the common things of life uncommonly well.,Unknown
18,2019-01-18,18,January,2019,Friday,"Keep on going and the chances are you will stumble on something, perhaps when you are least expecting it. I have never heard of anyone stumbling on something sitting down.","Charles F Kettering, Engineer and Inventor"
19,2019-01-19,19,January,2019,Saturday,Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things that you didn't do than by the ones you did do. So throw off the bowlines. Sail away from the safe harbor. Catch the trade winds in your sails. Explore. Dream. Discover.,Mark Twain
20,2019-01-20,20,January,2019,Sunday,Losers visualize the penalties of failure. Winners visualize the rewards of success.,Unknown
21,2019-01-21,21,January,2019,Monday,Some succeed because they are destined. Some succeed because they are determined.,Unknown
22,2019-01-22,22,January,2019,Tuesday,Experience is what you get when you don't get what you want.,Dan Stanford
23,2019-01-23,23,January,2019,Wednesday,Setting an example is not the main means of influencing others; it is the only means.,Albert Einstein
24,2019-01-24,24,January,2019,Thursday,"A happy person is not a person in a certain set of circumstances, but rather a person with a certain set of attitudes.",Hugh Downs
25,2019-01-25,25,January,2019,Friday,"If you're going to be able to look back on something and laugh about it, you might as well laugh about it now.",Marie Osmond
26,2019-01-26,26,January,2019,Saturday,"Remember that happiness is a way of travel, not a destination.",Roy Goodman
27,2019-01-27,27,January,2019,Sunday,"If you want to test your memory, try to recall what you were worrying about one year ago today.",E Joseph Cossman
28,2019-01-28,28,January,2019,Monday,What lies behind us and what lies before us are tiny matters compared to what lies within us.,Ralph Waldo Emerson
29,2019-01-29,29,January,2019,Tuesday,We judge of man's wisdom by his hope.,Ralph Waldo Emerson
30,2019-01-30,30,January,2019,Wednesday,The best way to cheer yourself up is to try to cheer somebody else up.,Mark Twain
31,2019-01-31,31,January,2019,Thursday,"Age is an issue of mind over matter. If you don't mind, it doesn't matter.",Mark Twain
32,2019-02-01,1,February,2019,Friday,"Whenever you find yourself on the side of the majority, it's time to pause and reflect.",Mark Twain
33,2019-02-02,2,February,2019,Saturday,"Keep away from people who try to belittle your ambitions. Small people always do that, but the really great make you feel that you, too, can become great.",Mark Twain
34,2019-02-03,3,February,2019,Sunday,The surest way not to fail is to determine to succeed.,Richard B Sheridan
35,2019-02-04,4,February,2019,Monday,"Take the first step in faith. You don't have to see the whole staircase, just take the first step.",Dr Martin Luther King Jr
36,2019-02-05,5,February,2019,Tuesday,Act or accept.,Anonymous
37,2019-02-06,6,February,2019,Wednesday,"Many great ideas go unexecuted, and many great executioners are without ideas. One without the other is worthless.",Tim Blixseth
38,2019-02-07,7,February,2019,Thursday,The world is more malleable than you think and it's waiting for you to hammer it into shape.,Bono
39,2019-02-08,8,February,2019,Friday,Sometimes you just got to give yourself what you wish someone else would give you.,Dr Phil
40,2019-02-09,9,February,2019,Saturday,"Motivation is a fire from within. If someone else tries to light that fire under you, chances are it will burn very briefly.",Stephen R Covey
41,2019-02-10,10,February,2019,Sunday,People become really quite remarkable when they start thinking that they can do things. When they believe in themselves they have the first secret of success.,Norman Vincent Peale
42,2019-02-11,11,February,2019,Monday,Whenever you find whole world against you just turn around and lead the world.,Anonymous
43,2019-02-12,12,February,2019,Tuesday,Being defeated is only a temporary condition; giving up is what makes it permanent.,"Marilyn vos Savant, Author and Advice Columnist"
44,2019-02-13,13,February,2019,Wednesday,I can't understand why people are frightened by new ideas. I'm frightened by old ones.,John Cage
45,2019-02-14,14,February,2019,Thursday,Setting an example is not the main means of influencing others; it is the only means.,Albert Einstein
46,2019-02-15,15,February,2019,Friday,The difference between ordinary and extraordinary is that little extra.,Unknown
47,2019-02-16,16,February,2019,Saturday,The best way to predict the future is to create it.,Unknown
48,2019-02-17,17,February,2019,Sunday,Anyone can do something when they WANT to do it. Really successful people do things when they don't want to do it.,Dr Phil
49,2019-02-18,18,February,2019,Monday,"There are two primary choices in life: to accept conditions as they exist, or accept the responsibility for changing them.",Dr Denis Waitley
50,2019-02-19,19,February,2019,Tuesday,Success is the ability to go from failure to failure without losing your enthusiasm.,Sir Winston Churchill
51,2019-02-20,20,February,2019,Wednesday,Success seems to be connected with action. Successful people keep moving. They make mistakes but don't quit.,Conrad Hilton
52,2019-02-21,21,February,2019,Thursday,Attitudes are contagious. Make yours worth catching.,Unknown
53,2019-02-22,22,February,2019,Friday,Do not let what you cannot do interfere with what you can do.,John Wooden
54,2019-02-23,23,February,2019,Saturday,"There are only two rules for being successful. One, figure out exactly what you want to do, and two, do it.",Mario Cuomo
55,2019-02-24,24,February,2019,Sunday,"Sooner or later, those who win are those who think they can.",Richard Bach
56,2019-02-25,25,February,2019,Monday,Vision doesn't usually come as a lightening bolt. Rather it comes as a slow crystallization of life challenges that we one day recognize as a beautiful diamond with great value to ourselves and others.,Dr Michael Norwood
57,2019-02-26,26,February,2019,Tuesday,"Success is a state of mind. If you want success, start thinking of yourself as a success.",Dr Joyce Brothers
58,2019-02-27,27,February,2019,Wednesday,Ever tried. Ever failed. No matter. Try Again. Fail again. Fail better.,Samuel Beckett
59,2019-02-28,28,February,2019,Thursday,Flops are a part of life's menu and I've never been a girl to miss out on any of the courses.,Rosalind Russell
60,2019-03-01,1,March,2019,Friday,Cause change and lead. Accept change and survive. Resist change and die.,"Ray Norda, Chairman, Novell"
61,2019-03-02,2,March,2019,Saturday,"Winners lose much more often than losers. So if you keep losing but you're still trying, keep it up! You're right on track.",Matthew Keith Groves
62,2019-03-03,3,March,2019,Sunday,"An idea can turn to dust or magic, depending on the talent that rubs against it.",Bill Bernbach
63,2019-03-04,4,March,2019,Monday,An obstacle is often a stepping stone.,Prescott
64,2019-03-05,5,March,2019,Tuesday,Life is trying things to see if they work,Ray Bradbury
65,2019-03-06,6,March,2019,Wednesday,"If you worry about yesterday's failures, then today's successes will be few.",Anonymous
66,2019-03-07,7,March,2019,Thursday,Life is 10% what happens to us and 90% how we react to it.,Dennis P Kimbro
67,2019-03-08,8,March,2019,Friday,"We are all inventors, each sailing out on a voyage of discovery, guided each by a private chart, of which there is no duplicate. The world is all gates, all opportunities.",Ralph Waldo Emerson
68,2019-03-09,9,March,2019,Saturday,Knowing is not enough; we must apply. Willing is not enough; we must do.,Johann Wolfgang von Goethe
69,2019-03-10,10,March,2019,Sunday,"In matters of style, swim with the current; in matters of principle, stand like a rock.",Thomas Jefferson
70,2019-03-11,11,March,2019,Monday,"I think and think for months and years. Ninety-nine times, the conclusion is false. The hundredth time I am right.",Albert Einstein
71,2019-03-12,12,March,2019,Tuesday,"Where the willingness is great, the difficulties cannot be great.",Machiavelli
72,2019-03-13,13,March,2019,Wednesday,Strength does not come from physical capacity. It comes from an indomitable will.,Mahatma Gandhi
73,2019-03-14,14,March,2019,Thursday,You are what you think about all day long.,Dr Robert Schuller
74,2019-03-15,15,March,2019,Friday,What you do speaks so loudly that I cannot hear what you say.,Ralph Waldo Emerson
75,2019-03-16,16,March,2019,Saturday,"Success is not to be measured by the position someone has reached in life, but the obstacles he has overcome while trying to succeed.",Booker T Washington
76,2019-03-17,17,March,2019,Sunday,"Talent is formed in solitude, character in the bustle of the world.",Johann Wolfgang von Goethe
77,2019-03-18,18,March,2019,Monday,"To avoid criticism do nothing, say nothing, be nothing.",Elbert Hubbard
78,2019-03-19,19,March,2019,Tuesday,"If you want to make your dreams come true, the first thing you have to do is wake up.",JM Power
79,2019-03-20,20,March,2019,Wednesday,By working faithfully eight hours a day you may eventually get to be boss and work twelve hours a day,Robert Frost
80,2019-03-21,21,March,2019,Thursday,"I've learned that no matter what happens, or how bad it seems today, life does go on, and it will be better tomorrow.",Maya Angelou
81,2019-03-22,22,March,2019,Friday,The art of being wise is the art of knowing what to overlook.,William James
82,2019-03-23,23,March,2019,Saturday,"When I hear somebody sigh, ‘Life is hard,' I am always tempted to ask, ‘Compared to what?'",Sydney Harris
83,2019-03-24,24,March,2019,Sunday,Don't let life discourage you; everyone who got where he is had to begin where he was.,Richard L Evans
84,2019-03-25,25,March,2019,Monday,In three words I can sum up everything I've learned about life: It goes on.,Robert Frost
85,2019-03-26,26,March,2019,Tuesday,"You gain strength, courage and confidence by every experience in which you stop to look fear in the face.",Eleanor Roosevelt
86,2019-03-27,27,March,2019,Wednesday,Sometimes even to live is an act of courage.,Seneca
87,2019-03-28,28,March,2019,Thursday,"Do first things first, and second things not at all.",Peter Drucker
88,2019-03-29,29,March,2019,Friday,The only people who find what they are looking for in life are the fault finders.,Foster's Law
89,2019-03-30,30,March,2019,Saturday,Defeat is not bitter unless you swallow it.,Joe Clark
90,2019-03-31,31,March,2019,Sunday,I am an optimist. It does not seem too much use being anything else.,Winston Churchill
91,2019-04-01,1,April,2019,Monday,Positive anything is better than negative thinking.,Elbert Hubbard
92,2019-04-02,2,April,2019,Tuesday,People seem not to see that their opinion of the world is also a confession of character.,Ralph Waldo Emerson
93,2019-04-03,3,April,2019,Wednesday,"Those who wish to sing, always find a song.",Swedish Proverb
94,2019-04-04,4,April,2019,Thursday,"If you're going through hell, keep going.",Winston Churchill
95,2019-04-05,5,April,2019,Friday,"The sun shines and warms and lights us and we have no curiosity to know why this is so; but we ask the reason of all evil, of pain, and hunger, and mosquitoes and silly people.",Ralph Waldo Emerson
96,2019-04-06,6,April,2019,Saturday,Life is a shipwreck but we must not forget to sing in the lifeboats.,Voltaire
97,2019-04-07,7,April,2019,Sunday,"Enduring habits I hate…. Yes, at the very bottom of my soul I feel grateful to all my misery and bouts of sickness and everything about me that is imperfect, because this sort of thing leaves me with a hundred backdoors through which I can escape from enduring habits.","Friedrich Nietzsche, The Gay Science, 1882"
98,2019-04-08,8,April,2019,Monday,There is no education like adversity.,Disraeli
99,2019-04-09,9,April,2019,Tuesday,He who has a why to live can bear almost any how.,Friedrich Nietzsche
100,2019-04-10,10,April,2019,Wednesday,Adversity introduces a man to himself.,Unknown
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLloadrawdb[keys = {
    Number,
    Date,
    Day,
    Month,
    Year,
    DayOfWeek,
    Quote,
    Author
  }]
  {DailyQuote} % DB name
  {daily_quote.csv} % Filename

\raggedright
\DTLforeach
  {DailyQuote}
  {\Day = Day,
   \Month = Month,
   \Year = Year,
   \DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek,
   \Quote = Quote,
   \Author = Author
  }{
    \clearpage
    \section*{\DayOfWeek, \Month~\Day, \Year}
    \Quote~\textit{\Author}
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Werner, if some day (ex: 2019-01-10 to 2019-01-15) don't have quote, can display in these page (2019-01-10 to 2019-01-15) : blank or text "no data". Thanks

Comment: @TiSaigon: So you want the date for each of the days, but just have a blank (non-existent) quote? You can just leave the quote empty, no?

Comment: Hi, @Werner. How can i select day range from day A to day B in latex and push data from day A to day B in csv to pdf? i don't want delete rows in csv, only select and push data. Ex: 2019/02/1 to 2019/02/15. Thanks

Comment: @TiSaigon: Try [this paste](https://pastebin.com/SpTWYWCg). I added the use of the `Date` field (in the variable `\Date`) and compared it to your range.

Comment: Thank. i use your code v2 in pastebin and this can completed. But when i replace this filecontent with file daily_quote.csv = compile error/. In above code (version 1) i can compile with file daily_quote.csv. This my code in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BB0u33eE)

Comment: @TiSaigon: You forgot to add `\Date = Date` within the `\DTLforeach`. See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/SzSNL3Ai).

Comment: Thank. i format date in excel and in code different. Now all getting done

Comment: i tested some case. And difficult when get data (column Date) from excel to latex: Different Format. Can you give me other formula that i can get 3 columns in excel : IF (day column) & (month column) & (year column) = [02/02/2018] - [12/02/2018] . Thanks

Comment: @TiSaigon: Have a look at [this paste](https://pastebin.com/vuGaBrY3). I've added a number of things: Using [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) for managing conditional expressions like `\fpeval{(\Day >= 2) && (\Day <= 12)}`. `\fpeval` returns `1` if TRUE, and `0` if FALSE, so I use `\ifnum\fpeval(<bool expr>)=1 <true> \else <false> \fi` to condition on the boolean expression. Also, I've added a month number (`MonthNum` field in the CSV) since the expression involves conditions on integers. However, you can also use `\pdfstrcmp{\Month}{February}=0` to check for `February`.

Comment: Thank for your detail guide. something new when i want to display month calendar to this your recommendend code. [this paste](https://pastebin.com/ECYPgc5U). Maybe is conflict with tikzpicture and cannot display month calendar February - 2019. Thanks